# check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '07:28:29)' at line 1

Tags: php, mysql

I wanna insert record to MySQL but it returns error :

```
check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '07:28:29)' at line 1
```

I use PHP for connecting to database. here is what i write :

```
$id = 353567452;
$firstname = "My_name";
$username = "@myusername";
$message_date = "2017-01-01 17:29:20";
$sql_check = "SELECT id, firstname, username, register_date FROM RJ_userino WHERE id=" . "$chat_id AND firstname=$firstname AND username=$username AND register_date=$message_date";
            $sql_insert = "INSERT INTO RJ_userinfo (id, firstname, username, register_date) VALUES (" . "$chat_id, $firstname, $username, $message_date)";
            $check = $db_req->query($sql_check);
            if ($check->num_rows == 0){
                $db_req->query($sql_insert);
            }
```

And here is my column info :
[image]

where is the problem ?

Comment: while inserting no need to give registered date why becuase you are already using timestamp datatype in database while inserting it will automatically take the date and time my suggestion is remove register_date while insertion and check once..

Comment: for id also keep auto increment in datbase no need to pass in query...again

Comment: @Sona now it returns `Unknown column 'Sepehr' in 'field list'`

Comment: keep the query what you are using..

Comment: @Sona sorry what do you mean by keep the query?

Comment: keep sql insert query here i will check..

Comment: @Sona `"INSERT INTO RJ_userinfo (id, firstname, username, register_date) VALUES (" . "$chat_id, $firstname, $username, $message_date)";`

Comment: "INSERT INTO RJ_userinfo (id, firstname, username) VALUES (" . "$chat_id, $firstname, $username)"; try this

Comment: INSERT INTO RJ_userinfo (id, firstname, username) VALUES ($chat_id, $firstname, $username)"; and remove dot at the starting of values ..

Comment: @Sona it doesnt works

Comment: what is the errors it is showing for you

Comment: @Sona `Unknown column 'My_name' in 'field list'`

Comment: you are linking to  correct database table or not ...

Comment: the answer for abbove error is there is no column as My_name in table...

Answer (score 0):

$message_date should be a timestamp which is number eg. 1487230853

u can use the php function strtotime();

```
$message_date = strtotime("2017-01-01 17:29:20");
```

Comment: Actually the date is in UNIX Time and it received by PHP. it somthing like this `$message_date = 1487231132;`

Comment: - also you are inserting $chat_id which is undefined, u i think you may have to change that to $id in your code